# Sum up specific indices of an array to obtain another array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 1D array of length N, for example:

```
A = numpy.array([2.1, 4.5, 1.0, 6.5, 3.3, 1.9, 4.0])
```

and I want to sum up some specific indices of A to obtain a new array "B" of length M. The exact indices of A that I want to sum up are stored in a list like so:

```
idx = [[1, 2],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [1],
       [5, 3],
       [2, 2, 1, 4]]
```

So essentially, I want B to look like:

```
B = [A[1] + A[2],
     A[4] + A[5] + A[6],
     A[1],
     A[5] + A[3],
     A[2] + A[2] + A[1] + A[4]]
```

How can I achieve this in an efficient way? I have opted to not use for loops as the actual size of the arrays are a lot bigger than in this example, and this operation is executed several times in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
B = [sum(A[i] for i in indices) for indices in idx]
```

Comment: `np.sum(A[indices])` should do in place of the `i for i in indices`.

Comment: This would work, but I would like to avoid the use of for loops as it would be too time intensive for my case

Comment: Building the list you want to build is going to take an amount of time proportionate to the number of elements you want to add to it.  You will need some kind of loop; you can try to hide it inside a function call, or you can use `while` instead of `for`, but that won't make it any faster.  :)

Comment: I see, I think I will go with the suggestion. Thanks for the help!